# Application Error on when deploying git repo to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am deploying my repo on heroku but I keep getting application error. Note that Heroku and Github are connected. So the app gets deployed automatically

I have added engines to my package.json which does not seem to solve the problem

This is the error I get from heroku

```
2019-05-08T10:24:52.962552+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-05-08T10:24:52.962779+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-05-08T10:24:52.962913+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-05-08T10_24_52_957Z-debug.log
2019-05-08T10:24:53.021611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-05-08T10:25:08.906685+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=node-js-app.herokuapp.com request_id=f1847a93-53e4-43ad-8616-8867e95d31c3 fwd="105.112.44.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-08T10:25:10.823468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=node-js-app.herokuapp.com request_id=898935d3-5dda-4407-929a-20f13956b6dd fwd="105.112.44.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-08T10:27:19.725919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=node-js-app.herokuapp.com request_id=122efddd-b5f1-4cf6-b527-c429a787d0e0 fwd="105.112.44.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-08T10:27:21.466801+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=node-js-app.herokuapp.com request_id=e51dfc00-6b08-4601-ab61-8d490e6010c0 fwd="105.112.44.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-08T10:29:10.740930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=node-js-app.herokuapp.com request_id=abdd29b6-7106-4a2f-8133-3440f33dfd92 fwd="105.112.44.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-08T10:29:12.643465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=node-js-app.herokuapp.com request_id=264d0150-cbe3-4b5e-bccb-941b5ef84176 fwd="105.112.44.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

this is my package.json and server.js

```
"engines": {
        "node": "10.13.0",
        "npm": "6.x"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "test": "nyc mocha --require @babel/register API/src/tests/index.test.js 
        --exit",
        "build": "babel API/server.js --out-dir build",
        "start": "babel-watch API/server.js",
     }
    ...
```

Comment: What do your logs say? Try running `heroku logs`.

Comment: upload complete logs with error messages